# Phonegap installation issue via cmd nodejs [windows 7]

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

Im trying to install phonegap using the cmd 
"npm install -g phonegap"

but its not installing and giving me installation failed message ive pasted the cmd message below

so how do i set the proxy settings(assuming thats the issue) which nodejs can use to connect to the internet and complete the installation of phonegap

my system config is windows 7 64bit

> C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g phonegap
>
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
>
> npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>
> npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
>
> npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
>
> npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
>
> npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>
> npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nod
>
> ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
>
> npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
>
> npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
>
> npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
>
> npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>
> npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
>
> npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
>   (net.js:892:19)
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: what kind of proxy are you behind? have you tried this:  
`npm config set proxy http://server:port  
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Comment: It seemed to have an issue for me because I was running it from the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder - worked fine once I changed to a non-system folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it

Just had to set

```
npm config set proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port

npm config set https-proxy http://usr:pwd@proxyname:port

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```