# cannot install Phonegap on Win7

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm running Windows 7, and I'm trying to install Phonegap on my system.

I've installed NodeJS as requested, but whenever I try to install via

```
c:> npm -g install phonegap
```

I get this:

```
C:\>npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'c
onnect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! stack Error: connect EACCES
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm running command prompt as an adminstrator, so I know that's not the problem.  Any ideas, and failing this does anyone know where I can unzip the .zip file to install PhoneGap manually?

Comment: `npm cache clean` and try again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap installation issue via cmd nodejs \[windows 7\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656394/phonegap-installation-issue-via-cmd-nodejs-windows-7)