# installing phonegap on Windows 7 home premium issue

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I've been trying to install phonegap on my Windows 7 laptop for the past couple days and I can't seem to get pass a specific error.

14828 error Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\phonegap-build\node_modules\phonegap-build-api\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-max-data-size.js'

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

What I've tried so far

- tried running 'npm install -g phonegap' on both node.js x86 and 64bit
- running installation as admin (right click cmd -> run as admin)

The error message is telling me I'm missing test-max-data-size.js  in the path
When I go to the that folder, I do see other scripts (like test-handle-source-errors.js and test-delayed-stream.js) ... but not tast-max-data-size.js

The error suggests me to run as Administrator but I am already am ...

Is there anything I can try to further throubleshoot this issue?

Comment: still no luck installing phonegap 7 my windows 7 machine ... could anyone suggest what I else I can test ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap installation issue via cmd nodejs \[windows 7\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656394/phonegap-installation-issue-via-cmd-nodejs-windows-7)